# what is better SQL optimization and DRY code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, rails-activerecord, dry

Which is the best strategy for writing DRY code as well as SQL optimized?

Passing an optional parameter, subject_id, and passing @subject to the view only if this parameter exists as well as filtering "pages" that contain that subject_id in their record.

This:

```
def list
  @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC")
  if (params.has_key?(:subject_id))
    @subject = params[:subject_id]
    @pages = @pages.where("subject_id = ?", params[:subject_id])
  end
end
```

Or:

```
def list
  if (params.has_key?(:subject_id))
    @subject = params[:subject_id]
    @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where("subject_id = ?", params[:subject_id])
  else
    @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC")
  end
end
```

Comment: (This might work better in the review board, but) the second one is obviously more dry. Also, you should not test for the key, but the presence of the value. And you should not duplicate `params[:subject_id]`. And the great thing about DRY is you usually don't need to know what the code does just to start spotting the duplications!

Comment: I was trying to write the "first" one is dryer. Sry!

Comment: @Phlip: That makes more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with a slight variation of the first one:

```
def list
  @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC")
  if (params.has_key?(:subject_id))
    @subject = params[:subject_id]
    @pages = @pages.where(:subject_id => params[:subject_id])
  end
end
```

In either case, `@pages` won't hit the database until you try to iterate over it so both versions will be the same as far as the database is concerned. Furthermore, these two should be identical (or as close to identical as to not matter) as far as Ruby is concerned:

```
x = M.order(...).where(...)

# and 
x = M.order(...)
x = x.where(...)
```

so the above version of `list` is DRYer and should perform exactly the same as the more repetitive version.